# Sending Datagridview to email

Tags: c#, winforms

i made a code that i can send an email to gmail.com with c# and it is working very well.
Now i want to put my datagridview1 in the email body and send it.
Somone can show me how i can do that?
I searched a lot but i only found useless information and asp.net codes.

Here is my atual code of sending an email .
My datagridview name is : datagridview1

```
 private void btnSend_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Create a message with datagridview contents in its body and set up the recipients.





        var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("jpbritopoker@gmail.com", "*****");

        var mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.From = new MailAddress("youraccount@yahoo.com");
        mail.To.Add("jpbritopoker@gmail.com");
        mail.Subject = "This is the subject of the mail";
        mail.Body = "Here i want my datagridview1";
        client.Send(mail);


    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DataGridView` is a special tool of the Dot Net and your email (which gets open in a browser) doesn't know anything about it.

Besides, `mail.Body` accepts a string value :). you just cannot assign an entire datagridview to it i.e.

```
mail.Body = dataGridView1.ToString(); //wrong, utter useless
```

However, browsers does know about html. lets do one thing, lets create equivalent html table of your `dataGridView`

So what you should do is to iterate through each of the rows of your GridView and create html string and assign it to the `mail.Body`.

do something like below in your method:

```
 private void btnSend_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      string mailBody = "<table width='100%' style='border:Solid 1px Black;'>";

      foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
      {
            mailBody +="<tr>";
            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
            {
               mailBody +="<td stlye='color:blue;'>" +cell.Value + "</td>";
            }
            mailBody +="</tr>";
      }
      mailBody +="</table>";

      //your rest of the original code
      mail.Body = mailBody;
      client.Send(mail); 

 }
```

Comment: Error in row.cells it says that can´t be found

Comment: that's because we used var in the foreach loop, we have to provide strongly typed class name to the iterator

Comment: Thanks a lot , your answer is correct , but i get this : http://i.imgur.com/pgezOKa.jpg . How can i put the things with lines?

Comment: you can simply use inline css. infact you can use external css files.i am updating my answer on how to apply css;

Answer (score 3):

You need to iterate over the `Rows` collection of your datagridview, extract the values and assign to your `mail.Body`. A crude example: -

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (DataRow row in datagridview1.Rows)
{
      sb.AppendLine(row["ROW NAME"].ToString());
}

mail.Body = sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

The DataGridView is a WinForm-Control (or: an object) in the first place. What you could do is, for example:

1. walk through all data items of the dgv and create a table or list to set this to the email body.
2. you could export the whole object via serialization to xml/json, if you want to export not only the content but the whole object structure.
3. You also can add the serialized object as an attachment to the email.