# Sending datagridview as mail with header

Tags: c#, winforms, email, datagridview

This is my code to send datagridview as email. This code works for me by just sending the data in the datagridview.

Please guide me how to add the table header in it. I want the email to be sent as whole table including the table header.

```
var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("from_mail", "password");

var mail = new MailMessage();
mail.From = new MailAddress("from_mail");
mail.To.Add("to_mail");
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
mail.Subject = "test";

string mailBody = "<table width='100%' style='border:Solid 1px Black;'>";

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows)
{
    mailBody += "<tr>";
    foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
    {
        mailBody += "<td>" + cell.Value + "</td>";
    }
    mailBody += "</tr>";
}
mailBody += "</table>";

//your rest of the original code
mail.Body = mailBody;
client.Send(mail);
MessageBox.Show("mail send");
this.Close();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending Datagridview to email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16547588/sending-datagridview-to-email)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For converting your `DataGridView` to `HTML` for sending it in an email, use the function below:

```
private StringBuilder DataGridtoHTML(DataGridView dg)
{
  StringBuilder strB = new StringBuilder();

  //create html & table
  strB.AppendLine("<html><body><center><" + 
                "table border='1' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>");
  strB.AppendLine("<tr>");

  //create table header
  for (int i = 0; i < dg.Columns.Count; i++)
  {
     strB.AppendLine("<td align='center' valign='middle'>" + 
                    dg.Columns[i].HeaderText + "</td>");
  }

  //Close the header row
  strB.AppendLine("</tr>");
  //create table body
  for (int i = 0; i < dg.Rows.Count; i++)
  {
    strB.AppendLine("<tr>");
    foreach (DataGridViewCell dgvc in dg.Rows[i].Cells)
        {
            strB.AppendLine("<td align='center' valign='middle'>" + 
                            dgvc.Value.ToString() + "</td>");
        }
    strB.AppendLine("</tr>");   
  }

  //table footer & end of html file   
  strB.AppendLine("</table></center></body></html>");
  return strB;
}
```