# How should I send the DataGrid Result that im using DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs

Tags: vb.net

Below is the code for DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs

```
Public Sub DataGridView_CellFormatting(ByVal sender As Object, 
    ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) 
    Handles DataGrid.CellFormatting

    For i As Integer = 0 To dt_result.Rows.Count() - 1

        If dt_result.Rows.Count() - 0 Then
            DataGrid.Rows(i).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green
        End If

    Next
    Dim drv As DataRowView
    If e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
        If e.RowIndex <= dt_result.Rows.Count - 1 Then
            drv = dt_result.DefaultView.Item(e.RowIndex)
            Dim c As Color
            If drv.Item("Status").ToString = "Working" Then
                c = Color.Green
            Else
                c = Color.Red
            End If
            e.CellStyle.BackColor = c
        End If
    End If
    DataGrid.DataSource = dt_result

End Sub
```

Below is my Function for Send Mail Using SMTP

```
Try
    'Create instance of MailMessage Class
    Dim msg As New MailMessage()
    'Assign From mail address
    msg.From = New MailAddress("Emailaddress")
    'Set To mail address
    msg.[To].Add(New MailAddress("Emailadress"))
    'Set Subject of mail
    msg.Subject = "Subject of Mail"
    'Create Mail Body
    msg.Body = "Body of Mail"
    msg.Body += "DataGrid Result from DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs" <-- Here's my Target that DataGridResult will be here

    'for sending body as HTML
    msg.IsBodyHtml = True
    'Create Instance of SMTP Class
    Dim SmtpServer As New SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com")
    'Assign Host
    'SmtpServer.Host = ""
    'Assign Post Number
    SmtpServer.Port = 587
    'Setting the credential for the sender
    SmtpServer.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("Email address", "Password")
    'Enable teh Secure Soket Layer to Encrypte the connection 
    SmtpServer.EnableSsl = True
    'Sending the message
    SmtpServer.Send(msg)
    LblMessage.Text = "Mail Sent Sucessfully "
           Catch ex As Exception
    LblMessage.Text = "Issue while sending the mail Please check."
End Try
```

Comment: That is some crazy code.  You need to do some reading and start again.  The `CellFormatting` event is to allow you to do custom formatting for each cell individually.  You absolutely, positively do NOT change the `DataSource` of the grid in that event handler. You need to provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of what you're actually trying to achieve.

Comment: See this. Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16547588/sending-datagridview-to-email

Comment: There is almost never a good reason to loop thru all rows in that event.  It is going to execute that code over and over for each cell.  You should take the Welcome [Tour] real soon to learn how the site works and be sure to ask a question.